# Reemplazar | en powershell

Tags: powershell

tengo el siguiente problema, necesito reemplazar un Pipe entre una "columna" de un archivo de texto que obtengo desde SAP con la siguiente estructura

[image: Archivo de prueba]

Como se puede apreciar en el archivo, las columnas son separadas por pipes, y el problema que tengo es que en la columna de texto algunas de las descripciones puede contener un Pipe en esta, entonces cuando importo este archivo a mi BD me manda error porque "piensa" que ese Pipe es un separador de columna.

Estuve tratando de crear un script pero no logro solucionarlo, mi idea sería algo como poner mi primer indicador en la columna de texto y el segundo antes de Período, ya que Período siempre se encuentra después de la columna de Texto, el script que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
$log = get-content D:\test\archivo.txt | select -first 1 -skip 9
$logg = get-content D:\test\archivo.txt | select -first 1 -skip 11
$archivo = get-content D:\test\archivo.txt
$pos_ini = ($log | Select-String "Texto").Matches.Index
$pos_fin = ($log | select-string "Período").Matches.Index

#$pos_ini = [int]$pos_ini+1

$pos_fin = [int]$pos_fin-1

[int]$res = [int]$pos_fin-[int]$pos_ini


foreach ($line in $archivo) { 
$logg.Substring($pos_ini,$res) -replace '\|',' ' | Set-Content D:\test\archivo.TXT

#   if ($line -cmatch "\|") {
#   $quitar = $line.Split($pos_ini,$pos_fin)
#  $quitar

  #$quitar = $line.Substring($pos_ini,$pos_fin)


   #$line |  out-file -FilePath "D:\test\archivo.txt" -Append
#  }
}
```

Lo que no se como hacer es reemplazar la linea donde contenga el Pipe y guardar todo el archivo

Comment: Hay un problema semejante en CSV  (comma separated values) cuando un campo contiene una coma.  En la definición de CSV, superaron este obstáculo usando comillas para delimitar un campo the texto que contiene comas.  Así :  "este campo, contiene una coma".  No sé si SAP tendrá una regla semejante.

Comment: Eso estuve pensando, pero la persona que me envía ese archivo dice que no ha encontrado la manera de utilizar otro delimitador

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta que cada elemento de la cabecera de la tabla tiene la logitud maxima posible para el valor podrias extraer cada valor basado en la longitud de los elementos de la cabecera.

```
#Obtener la cabecera de la tabla
$sHeader = Get-Content "D:\DemoFile.txt" | Select-Object -first 1 -skip 9


#Obtener las lineas de la tabla
$sTable = Get-Content "D:\DemoFile.txt" | Select-Object -Skip 11


$aHeader = $sHeader.Split('|') | Where-Object { $_ -ne '' } # Extraer Nombre de las columnas

$PSData=@() 
foreach ($sColValue in $sTable) {
    $aData=@()
    For ($i = 0; $i -le $aHeader.Count - 1; $i++) {
        $iStartPos = $sHeader.IndexOf($aHeader[$i]) #Inicio de la cadena a extraer
        $iEndPos= $aHeader[$i].Length
        $sData=$sColValue.Substring($iStartPos,$iEndPos)
        $aData+=$sData #Solo para crear un Objeto personalizado de powershell y visualizar los datos con Format-Table
        Write-Host $sData "|" -NoNewline #Imprimir cada Valor de la fila/linea procesada
    }
    Write-Host "" #Salot de linea en la consola
    #Object personalizado
    $PSData += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Ledger = $aData[0]
        Sociedad = $aData[1]
        EntidadCP=$aData[2]
        Ejercicio=$aData[3]
        NoDoc=$aData[4]
        PosDoc=$aData[5]
        NoImp=$aData[6]
        Texto=$aData[7]
        Periodo=$aData[8]
        MasCol=$aData[9]}
}

#Imprimir el Objecto Personalizado
$PSData | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Salida:

```
 93     |SOC      |ENT        |2019      |12345678   |    8     |   1     |PUEDE CONTENER UN| DENTRO DE ESTA COLUMN |   12   |               |
 93     |SOC      |ENT        |2819      |12345678   |    8     |   1     |PUEDE CONTENER UN| DENTRO DE ESTA COLUMN |   12   |               |
 93     |SOC      |ENT        |2019      |12345678   |    8     |   1     |PUEDE CONTENER UN| DENTRO DE ESTA COLUMN |   12   |               |
 93     |SOC      |ENT        |2019      |12345678   |    8     |   1     |PUEDE CONTENER UN| DENTRO DE ESTA COLUMN |   12   |               |

Ledger  Sociedad EntidadCP  Ejercicio NoDoc      PosDoc    NoImp    Texto                                    Periodo MasCol
------  -------- ---------  --------- -----      ------    -----    -----                                    ------- ------
 93     SOC      ENT        2019      12345678       8        1     PUEDE CONTENER UN| DENTRO DE ESTA COLUMN    12
 93     SOC      ENT        2819      12345678       8        1     PUEDE CONTENER UN| DENTRO DE ESTA COLUMN    12
 93     SOC      ENT        2019      12345678       8        1     PUEDE CONTENER UN| DENTRO DE ESTA COLUMN    12
 93     SOC      ENT        2019      12345678       8        1     PUEDE CONTENER UN| DENTRO DE ESTA COLUMN    12
```